# Converting Score to Grade simpler. Is there a simpler way to write the following code?

Tags: javascript

It is somewhat tedious writing all the else if statements. Is there a simpler way to write the following code?

```js
function convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(score) {
  // your code here
  if(score <= 100 && score >= 98) return "A+";
  else if(score <= 97 && score >= 93) return "A";
  else if(score <= 92 && score >= 90) return "A-";
  else if(score <= 89 && score >= 88) return "B+";
  else if(score <= 87 && score >= 83) return "B";
  else if(score <= 82 && score >= 80) return "B-";
  else if(score <= 79 && score >= 78) return "C+";
  else if(score <= 77 && score >= 73) return "C";
  else if(score <= 72 && score >= 70) return "C-";
  else if(score <= 69 && score >= 68) return "D+";
  else if(score <= 67 && score >= 63) return "D";
  else if(score <= 62 && score >= 60) return "D-";
  else if(score <= 59 && score >= 0) return "F";
  else return "INVALID SCORE";
}

var output = convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(91);
console.log(output); // --> 'A-'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter code is not better code always. You can write a very short version of this code by using ascii and some math tricks. But it will not be readable later by other ones. I think **readablity** and **performance** are two most important thing to consider.

```js
var limits = ['-','','+','+']
function convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(score) {
  if(score==100) return 'A+';
  if(score<59) return 'F';
  
  var lCode = 74 - Math.floor(score/10);
  var sign = limits[Math.floor((score % 10)/3)]
  return String.fromCharCode(lCode)+ sign;
}
```

```html
score : <input id="scoreBox" type="text"/>

<input onclick="alert(convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(scoreBox.value))" value="calculate" type="button"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Now I wished I'd thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing to notice is that if a condition is "true", your function returns. So the "else if"s can be replaced by simple "if"s... The other thing is that since your ranges are continuous, you don't really need to test for a max and min each time:

```
function convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(score) {
  if(score > 100 || score < 0) return "INVALID SCORE";
  if(score >= 98) return "A+";
  if(score >= 93) return "A";
  if(score >= 90) return "A-";
  if(score >= 88) return "B+";
  if(score >= 83) return "B";
  if(score >= 80) return "B-";
  if(score >= 78) return "C+";
  if(score >= 73) return "C";
  if(score >= 70) return "C-";
  if(score >= 68) return "D+";
  if(score >= 63) return "D";
  if(score >= 60) return "D-";
  return "F";
}

var output = convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(91);
console.log(output); // --> 'A-'
```

I don't know if you count this as less tedious? Personally, my preferred way is to make a data structure mapping limits to values, end then simple loop on that until I find the right value.

```
function convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(score) {
    if(score > 100 || score < 0) return "INVALID SCORE";
    var map = [
        {max: 98, grade: "A+"},
        {max: 93, grade: "A"},
        {max: 90, grade: "A-"},
        {max: 88, grade: "B+"},
        {max: 83, grade: "B"},
        {max: 80, grade: "B-"},
        {max: 78, grade: "C+"},
        {max: 73, grade: "C"},
        {max: 70, grade: "C-"},
        {max: 68, grade: "D+"},
        {max: 63, grade: "D"},
        {max: 60, grade: "D-"}
    ];
    for(var loop = 0; loop < map.length; loop++) {
        var data = map[loop];
        if(score >= data.max) return data.grade;
    }
    return "F";
}
```

You still have the tedious job of defining your map though - I don't think you can avoid it in a case like this one.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Answered a while ago, but I encountered this question too. I think the following provides a nice middle way between the other two answers:

```
function convertScoreToGradeWithPlusAndMinus(score) {
  if (score > 100 || score < 0) return "INVALID SCORE";
// sign logic
  let sign = "";
  if (score % 10 < 3) sign = "-";
  if (score % 10 > 7 || score === 100) sign = "+";
// letter logic
  if (score < 60) return "F";
  if (score < 70) return "D" + sign;
  if (score < 80) return "C" + sign;
  if (score < 90) return "B" + sign;
  return "A" + sign;
```

}

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you explain a bit more how your answer solves the problem? (The last curly bracket is not in code format. Add 4 spaces before it).